# Change text Background color of Specific word in a TextView

Tags: android

I want to change background color of specific word in `TextView`  :

Like image below

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my working code that you can use to highlight some part of string:

```
     private void highlightTextPart(TextView textView, int index, String regularExpression) {
        String fullText = textView.getText().toString();
        int startPos = 0;
        int endPos = fullText.length();
        String[] textParts = fullText.split(regularExpression);
        if (index < 0 || index > textParts.length - 1) {
            return;
        }
        if (textParts.length > 1) {
            startPos = fullText.indexOf(textParts[index]);
            endPos = fullText.indexOf(regularExpression, startPos);
            if (endPos == -1) {
                endPos = fullText.length();
            }
        }
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(fullText);
        ColorStateList blueColor = new ColorStateList(new int[][] { new int[] {}}, new int[] { Color.BLUE });
        TextAppearanceSpan textAppearanceSpan = new TextAppearanceSpan(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC, -1, blueColor, null);
        BackgroundColorSpan backgroundColorSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
        spannable.setSpan(textAppearanceSpan, startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spannable.setSpan(backgroundColorSpan, startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(spannable);
    }
```

Then in your activity, call like the following:

```
    int index = 3;
    String regularExpression = " ";
    String text = "Hello StackOverflow From BNK!";
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    if (textView != null) {
        textView.setText(text);
        highlightTextPart(textView, index, regularExpression);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: That code fails if the word you want to highlight appears twice, and the instance you want to highlight is the second.

Answer (score 3):

```
    String string = "As Soon As";
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(string);
    toolBarSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")), 3, 7,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
     yourTextView.setText(toolBarSpan);
```

What is Spannable & How it works ?
Attach the specified markup object to the range start…end of the text, or move the object to that range if it was already attached elsewhere. 
For more details please you can check [setSpan](http://goo.gl/U6neLI) of [Spannable](http://goo.gl/LruYVk) & also know how that start and end number is required (like in anser 3 & 7 in [BackgroundColorSpan](http://goo.gl/bvURuV)

**UPDATE**

Please use this working code

```
String mainString = "As Soon As";
String subString = "Soon";

if(mainString.contains(subString)) {
      int startIndex = mainString.indexOf(subString);
      int endIndex = startIndex + subString.length();
      SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(mainString);
      spannableString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")), startIndex, endIndex,
      Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      textView.setText(spannableString);
}
```

Comment: I want to change with specific word like String Def = rush_searh.getDefinition().replace("Soon","<font color='#EE0000'>Soon</font>"); tv_term.setText(Html.fromHtml(Def));

Comment: @NitinMesta In your top of code, I think that toolBarSpan will be replace with spannableString . Because you not declare toolBarSpan at anyware.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String str = "Some really long string goes in here";
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(str);
spannable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(
  getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black)
), 0, str.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
yourTextView.setText(spannable);
```

see this [link](https://medium.com/@tokudu/android-adding-padding-to-backgroundcolorspan-179ab4fae187#.4rka1yw8j)

Comment: I want to change with specific word like 
 String Def = rush_searh.getDefinition().replace("Soon","<font color='#EE0000'>Soon</font>");
tv_term.setText(Html.fromHtml(Def));

Comment: @muzamilsiddiq For that you have to take 2 or 3 different textview and set  background color of that particular textview.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Best way to change text background color of specific word in a textview Android

[image]

```
TextView txtMessage=findViewById(R.id.textview_msg);
String text="Hello World!";
String search_term="Hello";
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
{
  String newString = text.replaceAll(search_term, "<span style='background:
  yellow;'>"+search_term+"</span>");          
  txtMessage.setText(Html.fromHtml(newString
  ,HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
}
else 
{
  String newString = text.replaceAll(search_term, "<font 
  color='#f3f402'>"+search_term+"</font>"); 
  txtMessage.setText(Html.fromHtml(newString));
}
```